# Why does my custom Drupal module's config file return null?

Tags: drupal, config

I'm trying to use a config file in a custom Drupal module. I've followed the the instructions from the following resource:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/creating-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal

I've create a yml file in my module's /config/install/ directory.

```
$config = \Drupal::config('test_module.settings');
$lang = $config->get('langcode');
```

When I call $config->get('langcode') I get null.

This is the yml for the config file:

```
langcode: 'en'
test: 'test'
```